# How do I get the first layer index of 2D vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, stl

I need help getting the first layer index of a 2D vector. Each element is unique, so there are no repetitions of element. Here's what I mean bellow.

I have a vector defined as:

```
vector<vector<int>> vec { {0,1} , 
                          {2} , 
                          {3,4}, 
                          {5,6} }
```

Then, I want to get the index of where any of the numbers is, on the "first" layer.
By this, I mean if I say
`index of 4`, it should return `2`.
If I say, `index of 6`, it should return `3`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If we can allocate extra space, we can use an `unordered_map<int, int>` to store the numbers and the index of the vector they belong to. If not, then we'll have to traverse the whole 2D array unless there is more structure to the 2D array which you didn't provide.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It looks like they mean 'Find 4 and return its index within the subvector'

Comment: And if your numbers are contiguous starting from 0, then you'd better make a `vector<int>` where 1st element corresponds to a layer of 0, 2nd element to a layer of 1 and so on. O(N) space, O(1) access, and change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and `std::find_if`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec { {0,1} , 
                              {2} , 
                              {3,4}, 
                              {5,6} };

    // Search for the 4
    auto iter = std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const std::vector<int>& v)
                            {return std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 4) != v.end();});

    // Output the distance between the item and the beginning of the vector
    std::cout << std::distance(vec.begin(), iter);
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

The outer `std::find_if` searches the `std::vector<vector<int>>` and the argument to the lambda will be a reference to each inner vector.  The inner `std::find` searches that inner vector for the value.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function that calculates the index like:

```
int findIndex(const std::vector<std::vector<int>> &vec, int val)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), [val](const std::vector<int> &v) {
        return std::find(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), val) != v.cend();
    });

    return it != vec.cend() ? std::distance(vec.cbegin(), it) : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard algorithm `std::find_if` along with the algorithm `std::find`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v =
    { 
        { 0, 1 }, { 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } 
    };

    auto present = []( const auto &v, const auto &value ) 
    { 
        return std::find( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), value ) != std::end( v );
    };
    
    int value = 4;
    
    size_t i = std::distance( std::begin( v ), 
                              std::find_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
                                            [&, present, value]( const auto &item )
                                            {
                                                return present( item, value );
                                            } ) );

    if ( i != v.size() ) std::cout << value << ": " << i << '\n';
    
    value = 6;
    
    i = std::distance( std::begin( v ), 
                       std::find_if( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ),
                                     [&, present, value]( const auto &item )
                                     {
                                            return present( item, value );
                                     } ) );

    if ( i != v.size() ) std::cout << value << ": " << i << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4: 2
6: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash-table data structure like unordered_map to do this in O(1) time.

```
unordered_map <int,int> m;
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
  for(int j=0;j<vec[i].size();j++){
    m[vec[i][j]] = i;
  }
}
```